# Check CPU consumption by specific part of a program

Tags: python, python-3.x, cpu, cpu-usage

I've a python application which is consuming fairly large amount of CPU ~55-60%. But ideally it should have been using ~35-40% (I'm saying this because there is another program of mine which shares around 80% code and it's utilization is fairly low).

It's got something to do with the rest 20% code which I would like to check.

Is there any python library or a method using which I can determine which part of my program is using how much CPU?

MRE:

```
# import necessary libraries 

import cv2 
import numpy as np 

# Turn on Laptop's webcam 
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0) 


while True: 
    
    ret, frame = cap.read() 

    # Locate points of the documents or object which you want to transform 
    pts1 = np.float32([[0, 260], [640, 260], [0, 400], [640, 400]]) 
    pts2 = np.float32([[0, 0], [400, 0], [0, 640], [400, 640]]) 
    
    # Apply Perspective Transform Algorithm 
    matrix = cv2.getPerspectiveTransform(pts1, pts2) 
    result = cv2.warpPerspective(frame, matrix, (500, 600)) 
    # Wrap the transformed image 

    cv2.imshow('frame', frame) # Inital Capture 
    cv2.imshow('frame1', result) # Transformed Capture 

    if cv2.waitKey(24) == 27: 
        break

cap.release() 
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Try this https://github.com/pyutils/line_profiler and this https://github.com/plasma-umass/scalene

Comment: @alec_djinn Could you provide a working example?

Comment: Check the site linked, they have examples there.

Comment: @alec_djinn the ```scalene``` module doesn't work on windows and ```liner_profiler``` is giving me errors when I try to install  it. Could you suggest any other method?